# SQL Server - Summarize date ranges across rows while preserving gaps

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I was wondering if this was possible but I think my wording for it might be why I'm having a hard time looking for it.

Here's my scenario.

See the below Select Result?

```
| Column A | Column B | Column C |
|   001    | 09-10-20 | 09-11-20 | 
|   001    | 09-11-20 | 09-16-20 | 
|   001    | 09-16-20 | 10-20-20 | 
|   001    | 10-20-20 | 11-11-20 | 
|   001    | 11-12-20 | 11-13-20 | 
|   001    | 11-14-20 | 11-16-20 | 
|   001    | 11-16-20 | 11-20-20 | 
|   001    | 11-20-20 | 11-21-20 |
```

Is there a way to have it output as v ?

```
| Column A | Column B | Column C |
|   001    | 09-10-20 | 11-11-20 | 
|   001    | 11-12-20 | 11-13-20 | 
|   001    | 11-14-20 | 11-21-20 |
```

Honestly so far I think this seems unlikely using just SQL but I thought I'd still ask it.

I've looked and I did see ways to identify gaps and to identify overlaps but I still can't wrap my head around how I would get around to doing this with just SQL.

Normally I'd just have another piece of code outside SQL sift through the output and give me Table B from Table A. But that requires additional overhead and I'd rather just learn how to do it in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()` and a cumulative sum to define the groups.  Then aggregate:

```
select a, min(b), max(c)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_c >= c then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by a order by b) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(c) over (partition by a order by b) as prev_c
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by a, grp;
```

This problem is an example of a gaps-and-islands problem.  Using `lag()` and cumulative sums to identify the "islands" is one solution to these types of problems.

Comment: Thank You! It wasn't 1:1 but this led me to the exact solution I needed.

Answer (score 0):

A classical way to do that by SNODGRASS is :

```
WITH T  
AS (SELECT F.[Column B], L.[Column C], F.[Column A]
    FROM   T_INTERVAL_ITV AS F  
           JOIN T_INTERVAL_ITV AS L  
                ON F.[Column C] <= L.[Column C]
                   AND F.[Column A] = L.[Column A]
           INNER JOIN T_INTERVAL_ITV AS E      
                 ON F.[Column A] = E.[Column A]  
    GROUP  BY F.[Column B], L.[Column C],  F.[Column A]  
    HAVING COUNT(CASE  
                    WHEN (E.[Column B] < F.[Column B] AND F.[Column B] <= E.[Column C])  
                          OR (E.[Column B] <= L.[Column C] AND L.[Column C] < E.[Column C])
                    THEN 1  
                 END) = 0)  
SELECT [Column A], [Column B], MIN([Column C]) AS [Column C]  
FROM   T  
GROUP  BY [Column A], [Column B];
```